# netbeans not opening projects

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans

netbeans not opening projects

click on -> file -> open project
in open project window:
contacteditor_v0
guiformexamples
javaapplication1

clicking on any of the three project, then open project button, results in a popup that is there for a second. not enough to see what it was.

under project tab:

os: kubuntu 14.xx [dont know how to find which version]
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 (Build 20121011-unknown-revn)
Java: 1.7.0_121; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 24.121-b00
System: Linux version 4.2.0-42-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)

wondering if netbeans is not fully/properly making a project

23/03/17
started trying again last night.
1. can not create a new file.
2. .form files do not load. they just display form options, and window that buttons and things are to be dragged and dropped in, displays "loading...."
3. file that is open does not let new line to be added, but does allow new text to be added.

Comment: What type of project is it? Java maven or ant? Do you have pom.xml or build.xml file in project root?

Comment: Saljack, it is the projects created by netbeans. and they do have build.xml.  they are jave projects. if i try to open folder with netbeans, then a pop-up window appears for lessthan a second, and can not tell what is suppose to be in it.

Comment: still no answer/hints/clues?